# create a global function in python

Tags: python, global-variables, global

In python how can I create a function that can be global an used in all classes that are called?
Here is an example:

```
import configparser
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from ftplib import FTP

def notify(msg):
    echo = True
    log = True
    if echo:
        print(msg)
    if log:
        f = open('log.txt','a')
        msg = datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")+': ' + msg
        f.write(msg)
        f.close()
    #sys.exit()  #removing this was the fix!

class zoneFTP():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = FTP()
        self.dir = './'
        notify('The dir is :' + self.dir)

def main():
    notify('starting')
    ftp = zoneFTP()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Calling `notify()` in the zoneFTP class fails. How can I make the `notify()` function like one of the python built in functions so that it can be called anywhere? Or is there a better way of doing what I am trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Check the error message you're getting.  There should be no reason you can't call notify() from the class initializer, but the class name FTP is not declared.

Comment: Your notify calls `sys.exit()`, so the the call to zoneFTP() in main will never be reached.

Comment: @Steve Correct, The above code is picked from a larger project I am working on, I missed that part. I fixed the code example.

Comment: @Keith Thanks, I'm new to python and totally forgot I had that in there. It works just fine now!

Comment: haha, throwing sys.exit in random functions is generally a bad idea!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `notify()` in a utility module and have all the other modules import it.

Comment: This is a good idea, and as I get more functions like this I may start using this method, removing sys.exit() fixed the problem.