# Does "Python closure" apply to function object?

Tags: python, function, class, closures, global

I have 2 py files in the same folder (IDE Pycharm):

module1.py contains:

```
def test_func():
    return "test_func"

class test_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._test = test_func()
```

driver.py contains:

```
from module1 import test_class
obj = test_class()
print obj._test
```

I was expecting the the driver.py to fail with as the class instantiation requires the `test_func()` to be in scope.

To my surprise it didn't fail. I am not sure why (in fact there are a few posts in Stack Overflow asking about how to make function globally available to be used inside of class).

Is there such thing as "closure" on function object?

What is the difference between my 'imaginary problem' and this SO question? [create a global function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761408/create-a-global-function-in-python)

**EDIT**

As explained below, the SO question was to do with calling sys.exit. It has nothing to do with the function scope per say.

Comment: When `self._test = test_func()` is run, Python looks first in the function namespace for the name `test_func`, and failing to find it, looks to the next level -- the module namespace. There isn't really a closure involved, I don't think. Note also that the name is only resolved when `__init__` runs... not when it is defined.

Comment: there is no `__init__.py` in the same folder. the driver.py specifically import only the class definition not the entire content of the file. How could python actually find the this function? otherwise there is never a need to import anything as long as they are in the same folder?

Comment: This isn't a closure (they are functions defined in functions). A class's global namespace is the module where the class is defined, not the module where the class happens to be used. When `driver.py` instantiates `test_class`, `module1.py` is used to lookup names. It would be bizarre any other way. Imagine if you always needed to implement all supporting functions just to instantiate someone else's class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test_func` is "in scope" within the class implementation. It is not visible from *driver.py* since it is not imported. Python using lexical scoping so the scope is determined at *compile time*. Everything within *module1.py* is available to the implementation of `test_class` regardless of where it is called from. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) on scoping explains the difference between lexical and dynamic scoping.

Comment: Ok, i am ok with the class scope explaination. but i thought i would have the same problem as this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761408/create-a-global-function-in-python Maybe i need some sleep.

Comment: The problem in the linked question was due to a call to sys.exit within notify exiting the program.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the answers and explanations. Some sleep is needed for sure.

Comment: I do think that SO question should not mark that reply as the answer. or at least it need a better explanation in the answer